# Which cells are responsible for the extracellular matrix remodeling?

Tags: cell-biology, tendons, extra-cellular-matrix

I am studying a case of tendinopathies induced by an alteration of how the extracellular matrix is being remodeled.

From my understanding there has to be a careful balance of MMP (metallproteinases) and TIMP enzymes to maintain tendon homeostasis.

Which cells produce these enzymes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [The role of matrix metalloproteinases (MMPs) in the pathophysiology of chronic obstructive pulmonary disease](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/entrez?db=pubmed&cmd=Search&doptcmdl=Citation&defaultField=Title%20Word&term=Belvisi%5Bauthor%5D%20AND%20The%20role%20of%20matrix%20metalloproteinases%20%28MMPs%29%20in%20the%20pathophysiology%20of%20chronic%20obstructive%20pulmonary%20disease%20%28COPD%29%3a%20a%20therapeutic%20role%20for%20inhibitors%20of%20MMPs?)

> Metalloelastase (MMP-12) is (as the name suggests) capable of
>   degrading elastin, as well as other extra-cellular matrix components.
>   It is produced predominantly by infiltrating macrophages and appears
>   essential for macrophage migration through extra-cellular matrix

[Matrix Metalloproteinases in Cancer Cell Invasion](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK6598/) gives a more thorough description of the various MMP and TIMP types

> MMPs are mainly produced by nonmalignant stromal cells in malignant
>   tumors. Tumor cells also secrete factors, such as extracellular MMP
>   inducer (EMMPRIN), which enhance the expression of MMPs by stromal
>   fibroblasts (see Toole, in this book). In addition, growth factors and
>   cytokines secreted by tumor-infiltrating inflammatory cells as well as
>   by tumor or stromal cells modulate MMP expression.

Comment: Thanks for your input... I am trying to understand how Fluoroquinolone drugs can degrade tendons. From what I am understand MMP-9 is of my concern:

"Our study provides preliminary evidence that topical application of fluoroquinolone drugs can induce the expression of MMP-1, MMP-2, MMP-8 and MMP-9 in the undebrided corneal epithelium compared to artificial tear eye drops." (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK6598/)

Comment: Here's another one:
http://www.wikigenes.org/e/ref/e/12428247.html
Ciprofloxacin enhances the stimulation of matrix metalloproteinase 3 expression by interleukin-1beta in human tendon-derived cells. A potential mechanism of fluoroquinolone-induced tendinopathy.